# iterator over 3d array indices

Tags: c++, 3d, iterator

I am writing code dealing with gridded data in 3d (boost::multi_array and vtkImageData). I find that I have nested loops

```
for(int i=0; i<shape[0]; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<shape[1]; j++){
      for(int k=0; k<shape[2]; k++){
         /* ... */
      }
   }
}
```

in my code more often than I aesthetically like; what is the proper way to write this using iterators holding the three indices in fixed-size array (like `boost::array`)?

The goal would be to write something akin to:

```
for(boost::array<int,3> ijk: GridIndicesIterator(shape)){ ... }
```

boost::multi_array allows iteration through elements, but the 3d indices must be back-computed explicitly.  I've also looked at boost::iterator and it seems that writing iterator code properly is quite an undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use iterator pattern. You can check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern). You can think of having iterator for each dimension and iterating through them. Also you can think of passing `operator ()` as a parameter to iterator class and performing required operation.

Answer (score 0):

if you keep using this

```
for(int i=0; i<shape[0]; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<shape[1]; j++){
      for(int k=0; k<shape[2]; k++){
```

pattern all the time, you can try to use #define instead which is easy.